# Can you use a Try Catch in a stored procedure to "do" something?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have linked servers that need updates.

```
BEGIN TRY

delete [SDNY-PAND\BarCode].Barcodes.dbo.barcodes
where Plant_Location <> 'Jefferson,  GA123'

-- bla bla bla


END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

--print ' in error now'


set @strBody = 'It appears that the server that holds the barcode data
        is currently unavailable.  Please validate that it is plugged in
        and turned on for IS' 
set @MailTo = 'ThatGroup@work'  
set @ESubject = 'Message from Barcode Server Update Process' 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients =@MailTo,
        @body = @strBody,
        @body_format ='TEXT',
        @subject = @ESubject,
        @profile_name ='ColossusMain'

END CATCH
```

Will this process or is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, you can do this, it's exactly what TRY/CATCH is for. Did you try it? Have you had problems with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do better than this for checking linked server status, by the way. There is a built-in procedure called [sp_testlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189809.aspx). This will raise an error if the linked server is unreachable, preventing you from trying any deletes etc. and sending you into CATCH instead. If there are further errors due to the delete, say, CATCH will also be invoked, but ERROR_MESSAGE() will be different...

```
BEGIN TRY
  EXEC sp_testlinkedserver N'SDNY-PAND\BarCode';

  DELETE [SDNY-PAND\BarCode].Barcodes.dbo.barcodes
    WHERE Plant_Location <> 'Jefferson,  GA123';

  -- bla bla bla
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  SET @strBody = N'It appears...'
    + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ERROR_MESSAGE();
  -- ...
  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail ...;
END CATCH
```

If the server is unreachable, the error message will be something like:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SDNY-PAND\BarCode"
>   returned message "Login timeout expired".
>  OLE DB provider
>   "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SDNY-PAND\BarCode" returned message
>   "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online.".
>  SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].